# Refactoring into Vue Components: Readability vs Complexity

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

## Background

I have a large form in Vue that I want to refactor to make it easier to see whats going on from a developer point of view. i.e. I'd rather work on sub-sets of the form in different files instead of trying to work on a single file with 100s of lines of code.

The form is simple (just inputs with v-model binding to data), and the main bulk of code is in the `<Template>` tag that Vue uses.

To reduce the parent file, my initial go-to solution was to refactor different parts of the form out into their own components. This achieves my goal of creating an easier to read parent file, and be able to work on small areas of the form in isolation.

The problem however is that now I have to deal with the complexities of parent <-> child component communication. This is easy when you have one parent with many children, but once the child components are refactored further and they too have children, passing all the form data back to the parent becomes overly complex with standard Vue coding.

The go-to solution for this problem is to use Vuex. But here lies my question:

## Question

I've tried to improve the readability of my large form by refactoring into components, but in the process I've add the overhead of component state communication. Have I missed some more obvious way to refactor out my large form? Or do we just have to live with the complexity of components if we want to improve readability?